# Python (pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp) - Returning Values

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a variable  of the type pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp

```
type(dd_end)
pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp
```

the variable contains :

```
 pnl                   2008-11-26
 daily_returns_itub4   2008-10-24
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How do i slice it to get the Timestamp that refers to **daily_returns_itub4** ?

Comment: `dd_end.iat[-1]`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'iat'

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how a timestamp variable looks like a series with an index. How did you create this? Can you reproduce it with code?

Comment: Yes, second is Series and need `s = s.loc['daily_returns_itub4']`. It shoud working nice.